# Adding command button in p:schedule header

Tags: jsf, primefaces, schedule

[image]

How do i add a "custom" button in `p:schedule`? I tried doing it with the help of a header facet like in the `p:dataTable` component, but to no avail.

---

Sorry for being unclear initially, it also probably didnt help that someone butchered my question by editting it's title, here are more details with snippets of code.

I want to do somthing similar to this:

```
                    <p:tab title="#{bean.name}" value="bean" >
                        <f:facet name="title">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bean.name}"/>
                            <p:selectBooleanButton styleClass="...">
                                <p:ajax converter="... />
                            </p:selectBooleanButton>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:tab>
```

The code is creating a tab (for an accordionpanel) with a text+button in it instead of the default text only.

I am looking for the same behaviour in a p:schedule component.

```
<p:schedule value="#{scheduleView.lazyEventModel}" leftHeaderTemplate="today" centerHeaderTemplate="prev, title, next" rightHeaderTemplate="month, agendaWeek" >
        <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{bean.name}"/>
                <p:commandButton styleClass="..."/>
        </f:facet>
</p:schedule>
```

The same add a button to the header principle, except this time on schedule. And of course since schedule does not have any facets available for overwriting this approach does not work. 
Finally, my question is: How do I add a button in the p:schedule header like in the picture above?

P.S: Forgive me for confusing you people with `datatable`, used it because it supports multiple facets (header, footer).

Comment: Any code sample will be highly appreciated, in order to find whats wrong in your code

Comment: to change the default text add a script that is available in primefaces showcase : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml

Comment: You write datatable in the title, but in the picture and in the tag there is a schedule? And you mix two questions in one.. Please don't do that. Create separate questions with good titles and tagging. See [ask] and [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: i have updated the question entirely, please tell me if you still don't understand the issue

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS to position the button?

Comment: @JasperdeVries setting the x and y position of it will be a pain to make mobile friendly, id much rather insert it in the class holding the toolbar like Kukeltje suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client side it is all html that can be manipulated with javascript (jquery if you like).

So if you create your schedule and button like this:

```
<h:panelGroup id="mySchedule">
    <p:schedule value="#{scheduleView.lazyEventModel}" leftHeaderTemplate="today" centerHeaderTemplate="prev, title, next" rightHeaderTemplate="month, agendaWeek"/>

    <h:outputText value="#{bean.name}" id="scheduleOutputText"/>
    <p:commandButton styleClass="..." id="scheduleCommandButton"/>

</h:panelGroup>
```

You can move the `h:outputText` and `p:commandButton` into the schedule with [jquery dom manipulation](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).

```
$("#scheduleCommandButton").insertBefore(".fc-left");
$("#scheduleOutputText").insertBefore("#scheduleCommandButton");
```

If you put this script inside the panelGroup and update the panelGroup each time you'd normally update the schedule via ajax, the button and text should be added moved again in an update.

```
<h:panelGroup id="mySchedule">
    <p:schedule value="#{scheduleView.lazyEventModel}" leftHeaderTemplate="today" centerHeaderTemplate="prev, title, next" rightHeaderTemplate="month, agendaWeek"/>

    <h:outputText value="#{bean.name}" id="scheduleOutputText"/>
    <p:commandButton styleClass="..." id="scheduleCommandButton"/>

    $("#scheduleCommandButton").insertBefore(".fc-left");
    $("#scheduleOutputText").insertBefore("#scheduleCommandButton");

</h:panelGroup>
```

You could also put the text and button in a panelgroup and move that by dom manipulation. Just make sure you use the right selectors (I did not prepended the form id to the selectors above). You can also use class selectors instead of id's. That is up to you.

But make sure you use this with care. As @JasperDeVries mentioned in a comment, it is easy to break things. Use it just sparsely, carefully and only as a last resort

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, however no matter what class i select(fc-toolbar, fc-right) it just displays the button after the 'schedule' component https://i.stack.imgur.com/U30Xr.jpg

Comment: Then I suspect your selector is wrong OR it is browser dependend. I tried this in my (local) showcase and it works. But maybe try if the script part needs to be put in a '[document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)'.

Comment: found the issue, since i use a tabview and the schedule is not the default selected tab document.ready does not see the button because it is not redendered until the tab is clicked, now i just have to try to run this script on tabview change (maybe with ajax)

Comment: Upvoted, but take care when manipulating the DOM: one can easily break stuff.

Comment: @Kukeltje i will reward you the bounty in 10 hours, when stackoverflow allows it, thank you!